# Python Library Reference/Usage

Tags: python, libraries, biopython

I'm trying to use a method from the BioPython package to calculate an isoelectric point for a list of given peptides. The class breakdown can be seen here:

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam.ProteinAnalysis-class.html#isoelectric_point

In order to import this class to my environment, I'm using the following code (did I do this right?):

```
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis
```

Then, to call the method, I do the following:

```
window_aas = "ditkdteneveadveveadveveadvseql";
ProteinAnalysis.isoelectric_point(window_aas);
```

However I'm getting the following error, and I'm not sure how to interpret it, despite several searches for similar errors:

> File
>   "C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqUtils\ProtParam.py",
>   line 68, in count_amino_acids
>       if self.amino_acids_content is None: **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'amino_acids_content'**

Is anyone able to guide me in the right direction here? This other class is also called IsoElectricpoint but I don't see a method in it to use:

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils.IsoelectricPoint-module.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProteinAnalysis` is a class. What you're doing in your code is trying to call a method in that class directly. In Python, the first argument to such a function is the class object, but you're passing in a string (`window_aas`). The correct way to use this api is first create a class object:

```
protein_analysis = ProteinAnalysis(window_aas)
```

and then you can call

```
protein_analysis.isoelectric_point()
```

You can read up more on how this all works in the [online docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: You are wonderful my friend. This worked beautifully. Thank you for the explanation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `isoelectric_point` is an instance method, so you need to create an instance first:

```
analysis = ProteinAnalysis(window_aas)
analysis.isoelectric_point()
```